# Does www-data user need a real shell?

Tags: security, user-accounts

Interestingly enough, on my Ubuntu derivative  with nginx installed with `apt`, the `www-data` user has a shell:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
```

Shouldn't this be set to something like `/bin/false`? Even though the user can't log in, isn't it dangerous to provide a shell for a system user like this by default?

Comment: Not normally, but you may need it in your environment.  Try setting it to `/bin/false` and see what breaks.  If something does break document it and/or fix it.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything broke.

Comment: If something was going to break it would probably be related to some cgi/php/perl/etc script trying to run a shell command for some reason.  Which may be legitimate in some situations.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm pretty sure you can specify an alternate shell (something other than the login shell) for backtick or `system()` execution :)

Comment: That does seem to be the default on ubuntu, so on the bright side, on one's changed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `/bin/false` (or `/bin/true` if you're a positive person) is a real shell - it's just not an *interactive* shell :-) There's also `/sbin/nologin` on some systems which serves the same purpose.

As to whether your Apache user needs an interactive shell (something like `bash`), the answer as others have said is "Usually, no."
Setting the Apache user's shell to something non-interactive is generally good security practice (really all service users who don't have to log in interactively should have their shell set to something that's non-interactive).

Tour an existing environment like yours, try it, and see if anything breaks.
If nothing breaks use the non-interactive shell from now on.
If stuff breaks try to fix it *without* restoring the interactive shell :-)